# Why I cannot redirect in htaccess in this case?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect the url of a javascript file by using htaccess:

From:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/tracking/tracking.js
```

To:

```
http://www/domain.co.uk/Templates/domain.co.uk/tracking/tracking.js
```

After trying many things, now I've this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule tracking/tracking.js? http://www.domain.co.uk/Templates/domain.co.uk/js/tracking.js [L]
```

the problem is that with this configuration I only can access to the javascript code (the file) writing ......../tracking/tracking.js/   (with slash in the end, but I dont want it)

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.domain\.co\.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(tracking/tracking\.js)$ http://%1/Templates/domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: doesnt work......I spent the whole day making many experiments, and really look fine, I don't know what can be happening

Comment: with this:
RewriteRule tracking/tracking.js? http://www.buyometric.co.uk/Templates/buyometric.co.uk/js/tracking.js [L]

I can access, but only if I write ......../tracking.js/ (with the slash in the end)

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^tracking/tracking\.js$ http://www.domain.co.uk/Templates/domain.co.uk/js/tracking.js [L,R]`

Comment: in all the tester online works, and I see is logic, but however I see this in my broser:

The requested URL /tracking/tracking.js was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.0 (Fedora) Server at domain.co.uk Port 80

Comment: When you type `http://www.domain.co.uk/Templates/domain.co.uk/js/tracking.js` in the browser what do you get?